# Laravel Passport: get the authenticated user via api in web routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, laravel-passport

I have successfully authenticated users in my front-end via passport api.

But now i want to implement the Laravel socialite to connect/link their account to my app. So i want to get the authenticated user in `routes/web.php` because i put my redirects and callbacks in there.

I tried adding the `auth:api` in `routes/web.php` but still no luck.

Is there a way to get the authenticated user in web routes? or is there a way i can use `Laravel/socialite` with `Laravel/Passport` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know a way to get the authenticated user with this method:

```
Route::get('get/user', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
      $user = $request->user();
  });
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but that's not getting the authenticated user for non auth guarded web routes.

Comment: You can pass a guard that you're using to user method. It should work then. Like user('someguard');